# How to refactor validators

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, refactoring

I was thinking about a good implementation for validators. My service method starts like this:

```
if(badSituation()){
    return Response.status(400).entity("bad situtaion").build();
}
if(badSituation2()){
    return Response.status(400).entity("bad situtaion2").build();
}
...
if(badSituationN()){
    return Response.status(400).entity("bad situtaionN").build();
}
```

Since validators multiply really fast I have decided to refactor them to some design pattern. I was thinking about `Chain of Responsibility` or `Composite`, however I had a problem with practical realization. Can someone suggest how this code should be refactored?

Comment: *however I had problem with practical realization* IMO you should ask about your specific problem when trying to implement one of these design patterns.

Comment: I prefer to throw a business exception from  my service layer and implement a JAX-RS exception mapper to have a common way of converting to a 400 response: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html

Comment: @samlewis that might be it. If someone will not suggest better solution I will go with this.

Comment: You can come up with a solution using a CoR: You can define a kind of validation chain, which may throw an exception (= validation error) during the validation process. If so, in your catch block you can use an exception mapper as @samlewis suggested to convert the exception into a Response. The added value of the validation chain is that it will improve your logic maintainability. (I can suggest you a design sample, it's classic CoR implementation)

Comment: @yechabbi That is a pretty good solution. Best so far. I think that design would be even better without application exceptions (Validator should just build response), but I am not sure about details.

Comment: @MarcinSzymczak throwing an exception is helpful as it helps short-circuit your (Service) logic without if/else (s). Give me some time to write you down a CoR based logic, you'll probably get a better picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Cor Pattern for the validation "Behavior" : Each of your validators would implement a base `ChainedValidator` interface (some of the behavior can be moved to a parent abstract class as it is the same for all chain members):

```
    public class MyFirstValidator implements ChainedValidator{
        //This CoR implementation has also a 'Composite' background
        ChainedValidator nextValidator;

        @Override
        private void doValidate(Request request) throws ValidationException
        {
              if(badSituation){
                    //throw validation exception
              }
        }

        @Override
        public void doChainValidate(Request request) throws ValidationException
        {//This method can be moved to a parent abstract class
              doValidate(request);
              if(nextValidator!=null){
                    nextValidator.doChainValidate(request);
              }
        }

        private void attachValidator(ChainedValidator newValidator) throws ValidationException
        {//same as previous method
              if(nextValidator!=null){
                    nextValidator.attachValidator(request);
              }else{
                    nextValidator=newValidator;
              }
        }
        //setters & other methods
    }
```

On your Controllers/Web tier Service classes, you can inject the first `ChainedValidator` of the validation chain and call `doChainValidate` :

```
public class WebTierService{

    ChainedValidator validator;

    public Response serviceMethod(Request request){
        try{
            //...
            validator.doChainValidate(request);
            //...
        }catch(ValidationException e){

            return Response.status(400).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, the logic is 'fluid' (No if else check depending on type of validation error) and adding a new validator is relatively simple (`validator.attachValidator()`) which makes the logic extensible and clean.